# Using options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use

```
options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
```

But I am unable to pass proper parameter to it. What should be type on `collection` element? (Sample for complete usage will be helpful)

I have to use it with format like `Name=AL` and `ID=23`, like it is State name and it Code.

So for using how should I provide the collection object to it.

I have tried with `Hash`, `Map` and `Array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st parameter of [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) should be an arbitrary collection (accuratley any objects which has a [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method), for example an `Array`.

Example with `Array` of `Hash`es:

```
options_from_collection_for_select([ { :id => 1, :name => 'Foo' }, { :id => 2, :name => 'Bar' } ], 'to_s', 'to_s')
```

Of course this is a stupid example, because the 2nd parameter is the method for the value and the 3rd is the method of the name. So the method will call the `to_s` methods on the `Hash` items to fetch the `id` and `value` for the `<option/>`, so this will produce:

```
'<option value="{:id=&gt;1, :name=&gt;&quot;Foo&quot;}">{:id=&gt;1, :name=&gt;&quot;Foo&quot;}</option>\n<option value="{:id=&gt;2, :name=&gt;&quot;Bar&quot;}">{:id=&gt;2, :name=&gt;&quot;Bar&quot;}</option>'
```

If you provide proper objects, for example `ActiveRecord::Base` objects:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(Article.all, 'id', 'title')
```

It will produce a better output:

```
'<option value="28">FooBar</option>\n<option value="29">BarFoo</option>'
```

Comment: What is Article.All, i am getting following error undefined method `name' for {"name"=>"AL", "id"=>1}:Hash

Comment: `Article.all` will fetch all articles from the DB, it's just an example here. You're getting error because the `name` method does not exist for `Hash` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try options_for_select.

```
options_for_select([text1, value1], [text2, value2]])
```